# How do I control all the link tags in html from one location?

Tags: html

I am modifying my code for my website. I want all the links to open in a new window. However, instead of adding:

```
target="_blank"
```

for all the links, I was wondering if I could somehow control all link tags from one location.

Answer (score 6):

You can try adding a base tag to the head of the html

```
<base target="_blank">
```

http://jsbin.com/ezeyij/1/edit

Note: This also affects the target of forms as well.

Comment: Neat pure-html method, didn't know this existed!

Comment: This works great but now all the links to other pages in my site open in a new window. Any thoughts?

Comment: @WasiurRahman dosen't those links count as `all the links`, anyway you should edit the question to reflect what you actually want.

Comment: @WasiurRahman It doesn't seem to be a way with `base` to to only specify the target for links on the same site.

Answer (score 2):

You really should give us more info. Are you using some CMS? Is it a website written from scratch?

You could set all links on a page to open in new tab with a bit of javascript. Assuming you have jQuery included on your page you could do:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').prop('target', '_blank');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9p4P2/

Or if you don't use jQuery you could go with native JavaScript:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
```

EDIT:

If you wanted only links linking to other websites to open in new windows you could do:

```
$(function() {
    $("a[href^='http://']").prop('target', '_blank');
});
```